# preventing user from entering prior date in userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Im tying to prevent a user from entering an effective date that is prior to todays date in a text box up at the top of the userform.

the logic here seems fit, but im getting the msgbox even if the date is after todays date.

```
Private Sub txtEffective_Date_Change()
    If IsDate(txtEffective_Date) Then
        If cdate(txtEffective_Date) < Date Then
            MsgBox "Date chosen is prior to today's date"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I figure it has something to do with the `cdate` vs. `date`, but not entirely sure what's going wrong here.

[image: events i see in code editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change event is firing for every keystroke, causing the issue you are experiencing.  Simply move this code to another event, such as LostFocus or Validate, and you will be fine.

Edit:  since this is VBA and not VB6, try the Exit event.

Comment: not seeing either of those two events. I double clicked the text box for effective date and saw this drop down for the field (pic in my edited post)

Comment: I was still in VB6 mode.  Try the Exit event.

Answer (score 1):

For any one trying to do it on change event. You need to first ensure that your date is correct before doing comparison. e.g. 5/5 input becomes 5th may 2020 on CDate. Wait for the input to be correct and then compare.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim sDate As String
        
    If TextBox1.Text Like "??[/-]??[/-]????" Or _
        TextBox1.Text Like "?[/-]?[/-]????" Or _
        TextBox1.Text Like "?[/-]??[/-]????" Or _
        TextBox1.Text Like "??[/-]?[/-]????" Then
        
        sDate = Format(CDate(TextBox1.Text), "dd/MMM/YYYY")
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If IsDate(sDate) Then
        If CDate(sDate) < Date Then
            MsgBox "Previous date is not allowed...." + sDate
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: quite clean and useful.